# Replicate changes made on one EC2 to another EC2 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two ec2 servers named Ec2-Webserver-1 and EC2-WebServer-2 inside same VPC under two different subnets served by Application Load Balancer.

When I made small changes to the first servers, Then I have to manually change the another server too. Otherwise I have to create an AMI and create a new server from the AMI.

I think, creating AMI each time when I made little changes is not the appropriate one.

Is there any other tools in AWS or third-party tools that can auto replicate the changes made on Server 1 to Server 2? I am currently using CentOS AMI.

Comment: What changes do you want to make?

Comment: I am using these serves as my web servers. I have to make change in everything such as application configurations, package and tools install/update etc. @Dan

Comment: I would suggest look into cloudformation to define your ec2 instances. You can set environment variables for server config, IAM roles and more. The depdendencies for your application should be defined in the build script and independent of any EC2 provisioning.

Comment: wouldn't you use something like Chef or Code Deploy in order to script and apply those changes across servers? A lot depends on the nature of the change; but you shouldn't be *replicating* the changes - you should be applying them in an automatic fashion to all servers

Comment: @Felix code deploy is good for setting up build pipelines and you can probably manage some ec2 settings there, but cloudformation is the tool used for automating the provisioning of AWS resources.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest look into cloudformation. You can define your ec2, what IAM roles you want it to have and a whole lot of other stuff. Once that is done you can just run the cloudformation script and AWS will provision the EC2 with your defined settings automatically. [CloudFormation link](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/)

Comment: I respectfully disagree... Cloudformation builds servers **from scratch**; whereas OP wants to apply changes to multiple **existing** servers

Comment: @Felix yeah I guess I answered too quickly... I see that. I am a fan of the immutable AMI model and I think if 2 servers should have the same settings, that should be handled during the building of those AMIs and not configured later. One thing that can be done is to see if is possible to speed up the buidling of the AMIs. For example building the AMI and deploying in the same region can speed up the process of deployment.

Comment: My problem is that i have installed Memcached PHP plugin in Server1. I need to automatically install it in server 2. Is it possible? @Felix

Comment: @DeependraDangal... is that the only problem you have? And both servers are running the same application?

Comment: For now, it is the only problem.

Comment: how did you install it in the first server? manually? logged in to server1 and ran something like `sudo yum install php7-pecl-memcached`? That's my point - you *shouldn't do it*. You should put it into Code Deploy and apply it to both servers

Comment: What are you using to deploy your application?... I agree with @Felix... The installation of that should be handled by some kind of a build/deployment process using code deploy or something.

Comment: Can you provide me some refernces to use codedeploy to successfully solve my problem??

Comment: I'll put it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking into Code Deploy https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/getting-started/?nc=sn&loc=4 Possibly combine it with Code Pipeline. Here is a starting point for deciding whether you need one or both. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=172485

Comment: I would also suggest checking this out... it could be useful.... https://medium.com/devopslinks/deploy-a-php-application-on-ec2-with-github-and-aws-codepipeline-fb38cf204cbb